# Nan value in Impala_queries

Tags: apache, impala

I have a Kudu table with a column of type double, which has some values Nan.  So when I perform a sum function on the table, the query outputs the value Nan.  In Oracle there is a function called `Nanvl` which gets rid of the Nan values and does the sum function.  I performed the following query:

```
select case 
when Column_name ='NaN' then 0
else Column_name
end
from table_name;
```

The above query works fine in oracle but I am getting the following error in impala-shell:

```
AnalysisException: operands of type DOUBLE and STRING are not comparable: column_name= 'NaN'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select if(is_nan(Column_name), 0, Column_name) from table_name;
```

Comment: Not sure why but it doesn't work on my case. Still see NaN after using `if(is_nan(...))`

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey: is your column of a floating point type like `double`?  I wonder if perhaps you loaded the string 'NaN' into a column of type `string`.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out: I have to use `is_nan` as early as possible. I cannot do whatever calculation and then `is_nan` the result in another query.